# Wordpress notification based on advanced custom fields data

Tags: wordpress, notifications, advanced-custom-fields

I have posts on my website (custom post type) of which the content is filled from advanced custom fields input. The post also include a date field and an email address field. What I like to do is send automatic notifications to the email address when the date is today. Or even better 3 days before the date of today.

I've read some articles about using Wordpress php mail function but don't know where to start. Any points in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the Wordpress wp_mail() function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Make sure you are using a SMPT plugin so your email doesn't end up in spam.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

That should get you started, not sure how I would set up the job to send the mail, by I would definitely use wp_mail().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I think I need to make use of wp_mail() function. My coding skills are just not great enough to get it started. Hopefully someone created similar code and can give me a head start :-)